# Python OneHotEncoder Using Many Dummy Variables or better practice?

Tags: python, neural-network, machine-learning-model

I am building a neural network and am at the point of using OneHotEncoder on many independent(categorical) variables.  I would like to know if I am approaching this properly with dummy variables or if since all of my variables require dummy variables there may be a better way.

```
df  
    UserName    Token                       ThreadID    ChildEXE       
0   TAG     TokenElevationTypeDefault (1)   20788       splunk-MonitorNoHandle.exe  
1   TAG     TokenElevationTypeDefault (1)   19088       splunk-optimize.exe 
2   TAG     TokenElevationTypeDefault (1)   2840        net.exe 
807 User    TokenElevationTypeFull (2)      18740       E2CheckFileSync.exe 
808 User    TokenElevationTypeFull (2)      18740       E2check.exe 
809 User    TokenElevationTypeFull (2)      18740       E2check.exe 
811 Local   TokenElevationTypeFull (2)      18740       sc.exe  

ParentEXE           ChildFilePath               ParentFilePath   
splunkd.exe         C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin 0
splunkd.exe         C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin 0
dagent.exe          C:\Windows\System32         C:\Program Files\Dagent 0
wscript.exe         \Device\Mup\sysvol          C:\Windows  1
E2CheckFileSync.exe C:\Util                     \Device\Mup\sysvol\ 1
cmd.exe             C:\Windows\SysWOW64         C:\Util\E2Check 1
cmd.exe             C:\Windows                  C:\Windows\SysWOW64 1

DependentVariable
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
```

I import the data and using the LabelEncoder on the independent variables

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

#IMPORT DATA
#Matrix x of features
X = df.iloc[:, 0:7].values
#Dependent variable
y = df.iloc[:, 7].values

#Encoding Independent Variable
#Need a label encoder for every categorical variable
#Converts categorical into number - set correct index of column
#Encode "UserName"
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
#Encode "Token"
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
#Encode "ChildEXE"
labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
#Encode "ParentEXE"
labelencoder_X_4 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_4.fit_transform(X[:, 4])
#Encode "ChildFilePath"
labelencoder_X_5 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 5] = labelencoder_X_5.fit_transform(X[:, 5])
#Encode "ParentFilePath"
labelencoder_X_6 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 6] = labelencoder_X_6.fit_transform(X[:, 6])
```

This gives me the following array:

```
X
array([[2, 0, 20788, ..., 46, 31, 24],
       [2, 0, 19088, ..., 46, 31, 24],
       [2, 0, 2840, ..., 27, 42, 15],
       ...,
       [2, 0, 20148, ..., 17, 40, 32],
       [2, 0, 20148, ..., 47, 23, 0],
       [2, 0, 3176, ..., 48, 42, 32]], dtype=object)
```

Now for all of the independent variables I have to create dummy variables:

Should I use:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Which gives me:

```
X
array([[0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Or is there a better way to approach this this?

Comment: I usually prefer [pandas.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) from sklearn's OneHotEncoder. I find it easier to work with since you don't have to *fit* and then *transform* the data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm going to look into that one!  @Djib2011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use `get_dummies()`. get_dummies() method does what both LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder do, besides you can drop the first dummy column of each category to prevent dummy variable trap if you intend to build linear regression.

Example:
1. Create dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                 'C': [1, 2, 3]})
df.head()
A   B   C
0   a   b   1
1   b   a   2
2   a   c   3
```

2. Apply get_dummies():

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['A', 'B'], drop_first=True)
df2.head()
```

Output:

```
    C   A_b B_b B_c
0   1   0   1   0
1   2   1   0   0
2   3   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 2):

If your categorical variables include variables that suggest some numerical values like ranks, you should consider just label encoding them. (for e.g. First, Second, Third, and so on can be encoded as 1, 2, 3 and so on).

Also, find out if all these categories are important. Plot some graphs(such as histograms, distribution plots) to visualize the dataset. Remove categories that don't seem necessary.(e.g. in the above example, if First occurs more than 80%, you should consider if that certain features really contributes to your model.)